# Format the disk, disk has no valid partition

Tags: hard-drive

I got a hard disk to recover data from. I pulled the hard disk from his laptop. 
It works fine on the laptop but when I plug with any other PC it fails to work, saying `FORMAT THE DISK`. I have searched and found some password system on hard disk. Is there any method that can help him?

Comment: Dunno about your disk, but you don't need to shout in title ;)

Comment: Oh sorry.. no mistakes in future.

Comment: btw seems like it's business-class disk encryption scheme, where keys are stored in BIOS. Try to disable this via SETUP (if you have acces to original pc)

Comment: If the disk works on the laptop, why not just recover the data while it's in the laptop?  As @SzymonSzydełko mentioned, it sounds like the drive's encrypted, so if you want to use it in an external system, you'll need either hardware or software support for the encryption.

Comment: I cant the windows are corrupted

Comment: I tried the linux to recover but linux fail to discover the disk as well even on the same laptop. I tried to use the ntfs support package still no progress

Comment: @GreatMajestics If windows is corrupted then you might have an easier time repairing the windows installation.

Comment: :) Can it be possible if i am not the admin of the p.c

Comment: I know the password of bios, is there any tool which help me to decipher it

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Recovery CD at laptop. Easy Recovery Pro 6.22, R-StudiO 6.1.

Find data, save in external HDD, or network share.

Comment: It is protected through safe guard easy. If i boot through that drive i am able to load to the windows. So now thinking of a trick to copy to data in this state